# Pandas conditional cumulative sum by Rank

Tags: pandas, cumulative-sum

Find cumulative sum of customer sales for all customer below his sales rank.
Output is cum_sales column.

Example

```
| Customer | Product | sales | cum_sales |  rank |
|:--------:|:-------:|:-----:|:---------:|:-:|
|    Jon   |    Y    |   2   |     2     | 2 |
|    Abe   |    Y    |   3   |     5     | 1 |
|    Jon   |    X    |   10  |     17    | 2 |
|    ABE   |    X    |   5   |     7     | 3 |
|    RON   |    X    |   20  |     37    | 1 |
|   MIRA   |    X    |   2   |     2     | 4 |
```

How to do this in pandas. If looking at Jon with X product, his cum_sales value is sum of (Mira+Abe+Jon) only as their sales is below Jon.

What is thought is to rank them by sales and then sum sales of all customer below current customer rank. Don't know how to compare current value to all other value of column and apply function on that subset of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: provide expected output and show us what have you tried

Comment: I don't know how to do this in pandas at all. i need direction, i can start search from there

Answer (score -1):

first use group by in dataframe by sales and use max aggregation function 
 for eg

```
df.groupby('sales').max()
```

and calculate cumulative value using this code

`df['cum_sales']=df['sales'].cumsum()`

`